# Loading model from component

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to display a chart using Ember.js. I tried to load data from the model from the component "multiple-line.js" like so:

```
{{multiple-line dataset=model}}
```

**Route**

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('dataset');
}
```

**Models/dataset.js**

```
App.Dataset = DS.Model.extend({
  key: DS.attr('string'),
  values: DS.hasMany('value',{async: true})
});
```

**Models/value.js**

```
App.Value = DS.Model.extend({
  datasets: DS.belongsTo('dataset',{async: true}),
  xValue: DS.attr('number'),
  yValue: DS.attr('number') 
});
```

**Adapters/Application.js**
That start by :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    shouldReloadAll() { return true; }
});
```

**Server/Mocks/Datagroup.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var datagroupRouter = express.Router();

  datagroupRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      'dataset': [
          {
          id: 1,
          key: "Cbio",
          values: [
              {
              id: 1,
              "xValue": 1,
              "yValue": 21
              },
              {
              id: 2,
              "xValue": 20,
              "yValue": 150
              },
              {
              id: 3,
              "xValue": 40,
              "yValue": 200
              },
```

I didn't combine all the code for displaying my D3.js's Chart in the component. So How can I use Model/Adapter/Route/Component for this application correctly. Here is a [JsBin with the code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huqunotigu/3/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Your JsBin does not include `ember-data.js` so it will never run. Also, your data structure is fairly complex. I'd recommend starting with simpler models then add complexity. 

The way you pass the model to the component is correct, but the objects returned by your application adapter do not match your models.

Comment: how can I match my model to my adapter?

Comment: It actually depends what type of adapter your are using. You have the option to use the `RESTAdapater` (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) or the `JSONAPIAdapter` (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html). Ember data 2.0 recommends using JSON API Adapter which implements the JSON API specification (http://jsonapi.org).